# MongoDB can't start as a service

Tags: mongodb, centos

I am trying to run mongo as a service on CentOS 6, by using "service mongod start".

However, I get the "Failed" [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkTF1.png)

I checked the log file and there is the following error at the end of it:

```
IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /var/lib/mongo, terminating
```

I have given full permissions to the var, lib and mongo folders.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That image don't show any error details and you should avoid using an outside image as it can stop working and your question will make no sense. Please refere to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: full permissions to what user? perhaps you should see what user, perhaps it's not the one you gave the permissions to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo service mongod start`, from error, looks like it's not able to create lock file

Comment: I'm on root, so sudo doesn't change anything.

Comment: sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongo/ -R and then restart the service

Comment: This did the trick, but used "mongod:mongod" instead of "mongodb:mongodb".